# How to update a Branch using python-gitlab for Gitlab API?

Tags: python-3.x, gitlab, gitlab-api, python-gitlab

Im working on a small project which uses python-gitlab on its version 3.13.0

The project has a mixture of 2.x.x and 3.x.x features that i've been fixing, but there are a few methods for branches that i can't reproduce.

I saw a similar question for what im looking here [stackoverflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67794798/how-to-update-a-protected-branch-in-python-gitlab), but the given answer suggests to use `branch.unprotect()`, and that method along with `branch.protect()` is no longer working on 3.x.x versions on.

I've been digging into the docs https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/branches.html and https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/protected_branches.html but haven't found a direct way to reproduce those methods, any ideas about that?

Thanks in advance!

Im running these methods inside a few tests on a ci/cd in Gitlab, already got tests to create repositories, branches, retrieve them and delete, but havent been able to reproduce the protect and unprotect branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.13.0 seems to be an odd version to use - and it is two years old. Why not update at least to a more recent 3.15. or even 4.X.X? But I guess that might not even be the issue you are encountering here.

Have you taken a look at the [GitLab API docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/protected_branches.html#unprotect-repository-branches) for protected branches? From what I see in [python-gitlab](https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab/blob/v2.10.1/gitlab/v4/objects/branches.py) this is the endpoint used in both 2.X.X and 3.X.X versions. Only the method was moved as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68605574/2067865) in the post you already mentioned.

The calls seem to be pretty much straight forward and could worst case be called directly using the `requests` library:

```py
import requests

projectid=5
branch="*-stable"
headers = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': 'YOUR-TOKEN-HERE'}

requests.delete(f'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/{projectid}/protected_branches/{branch}', headers=headers)
```

The more challenging part is to find the right protection rule to delete if a wildcard is used for the protection rule! I assume that already was an issue in python-gitlab 2.X.X and maybe a reason to move the method (and reflect the structure of the API after all).